# <Response [200]> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, document-conversion

following the document conversion API example trying to use Flask to convert msword document to text, but it does not work.

Here is the code

```
import os, json, requests

from flask import Flask, jsonify

from watson_developer_cloud import DocumentConversionV1

app = Flask(__name__) #create flask instance

@app.route('/')

def Welcome():

    v = json.loads(os.getenv('VCAP_SERVICES'))
    svcName = 'document_conversion'
    svc = v[svcName][0]['credentials']
    url = svc['url']
    user = svc['username']
    password = svc['password']
    document_conversion = DocumentConversionV1(username=user, password=password,version='2015-12-15')
    # Example of retrieving html or plain text
    with open('./doc.docx', 'rb') as document:
        config = {'conversion_target': DocumentConversionV1.NORMALIZED_TEXT}    
        print(json.dumps(document_conversion.convert_document(document=document, config=config),indent=2))  

if __name__ == "__main__":

    port = os.getenv('VCAP_APP_PORT', '5000')
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(port),debug=True)
```

Here is the runtime log

```
File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__

return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app

response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))

File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise

raise value

File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app

response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise

raise value

File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request

return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

File "/home/vcap/app/welcome.py", line 39, in Welcome

        password = svc['password']

        document_conversion = DocumentConversionV1(username=user, password=password,version='2015-12-15')

        # Example of retrieving html or plain text

        with open('./doc.docx', 'rb') as document:

                config = {'conversion_target': DocumentConversionV1.NORMALIZED_TEXT}

                print(json.dumps(document_conversion.convert_document(document=document, config=config),indent=2))







if __name__ == "__main__":

        port = os.getenv('VCAP_APP_PORT', '5000')

File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 237, in dumps

**kw).encode(obj)

File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode

chunks = list(chunks)

File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 436, in _iterencode

o = _default(o)

File "/home/vcap/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default

raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
```

Comment: Can you post your code in a manner that isn't interspersed with log lines?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation appears to be out of date. The object returned is a [Response](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response) object, as seen in the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. In my experience, you can just use .text to get a string representing the JSON. I should say, you might have to use the .json representation to get something you can call .dumps() on.